# Jackson não serializa objeto JSONObject

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Eu tenho um serviço como esse:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestEndPoint {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response get(){
        POJO pojo = new POJO();
        pojo.setName("Rafael");

        return Response.ok(pojo).build();
    }

}
```

e funciona perfeitamente

mas com JSONObject, não funciona

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestEndPoint {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response get(){
        org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "Rafael");

        return Response.ok(json).build();
    }

}
```

Eu uso o JBossAS 7.1 com Jackson provider.

ps - eu tenho um web service com JERSEY e funciona perfeitamente com o JSONObject, mas com o RESTEASY não. Eu preciso fazer .toString pra que ele consiga gerar a resposta sem exceção.

Comment: Pode traduzir sua pergunta? Aqui é o SO em português.

Comment: putz, jurava que tava perguntando no .com, vou corrigir

Comment: A propósito, o voto negativo não fui eu, tanto que comentei aqui para te alertar.

Comment: Sem problemas, faz parte. O vacilo foi meu.

Comment: Qual exceção dá? Provavelmente precisará de um *provider* para este tipo de objeto.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Construa utilizando o JsonObjectBuilder:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("getnamejson")
public Response getnamejson() {
    JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    jsonObjectBuilder.add("name", "Rafael");

    return Response.ok(jsonObjectBuilder.build()).build();
}
```